# Load PostgreSQL table with composite primary key to QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgresql, unique-id

I would like to load a PostgreSQL table without geometry and with a composite primary key in QGIS (there is no unique column, see below).
This yields “ERROR” in all cells. It is not resolved by adding a SERIAL column.

The same occurs when loading using DB Manager. But the issue is resolved when I “Edit table” in DB Manager, using “SELECT * from *table*” and “Load as new layer”. If I select all records, DB Manager adds a unique *_uid_* column. If I select one subgroup from (id_name, sub_id), I can select the *time_* column as unique values which also works.

What am I missing for QGIS to load the table directly from PostgreSQL? Is a unique column as primary key required, or should I look elsewhere?

I am using a PostgreSQL/PostGIS database v9.4.6 and QGIS 2.14.9 ltr.

Table info:
Fields:
Name  - Type  - Length  - Null
id_name  - varchar - (30)  -  N
sub_id  - varchar - (30)  -   N
time_  - timestamp  - 8  - N
mtaw  - float8  - 8  - Y
mmv  - float8  - 8  - Y

Constraints:
Name  - Type  - Column(s)
timeseries_values_pkey  - Primary key  - id_name, sub_id, time_
timeseries_values_id_name_fkey  - Foreign key  - id_name, sub_id

Comment: Could you share a small sample of data to test? Do you know what the PostGIS log is showing in QGIS (access from bottom right speech bubble)?

Comment: I would think the unique ID field that QGIS requires needs to be of INTEGER type... even a dummy OBJECTID field of SERIAL type would work. Your primary keys are built on CHARACTER fields, which won't serve as unique ID's for QGIS to work with.

Comment: @raphael, thanks for the suggestion. The PostGIS log shows nothing if I submit the original table. However, after removing the keys I can view the data in QGIS and get the message below. Also, if I limit the number of records: no problem. I have to look at the data I guess. Thanks.  Message=  'Primary key is ctid - changing of existing features disabled (; "public"."test_full").'

Comment: @DPSSpatial, I understand your point about the required unique identifier. But I think the problem here is in the data and/or the primary key. QGIS is able to show the values if no primary key is defined, or if I subset the first 100 values (one id_name).

Comment: @haestp try creating an objectid field of serial integer type and set it to primary key - just to test editing abilities...

Comment: @DPSSpatial, sorry for the late answer. It works if I set primary key to a serial integer id column for the entire dataset. It works if I set primary key to a composite of character varying and timestamp columns for a subset, but not for the entire dataset. Therefore, I will have a closer look at the dataset. Sorry for the trouble and thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @haestp good stuff report back if you have any more questions!

Comment: @DPSSpatial, I had another look at the data and I guess it's due to the timestamp column in the composite primary key. The data load fine in 'Open Attribute Table' if I include any other column in the pkey. But as soon as the timestamp is included, only the last 10k records are shown in QGIS (bottom part). The 10k-exceeding rows to the top are shown as 'ERROR'. I can access all records in the Python console, they are just not shown in the Attribute Table. It's not that big an issue, just surprised me.

Comment: @haestp what's the intention of using a DATETIME column in a primary key??

Comment: @DPSSpatial, I know, that was not the best format. A SERIAL id column could have been a better option. Like I said: not a big problem in QGIS though, only in 'Open Attribute Table', probably due to the size of the timestamp key.